# Python/Discord.py remove milliseconds from time.time()

Tags: python, datetime, discord.py

I did this for my python Discord bot (basically it's a voice activity tracker), everything works fine but I want to remove the milliseconds from `total_time`. I would like to get something in this format `'%H:%M:%S'`

Is this possible ?

Here's a part of the code:

```py
        if(before.channel == None):
            join_time = round(time.time())
            userdata["join_time"] = join_time
        elif(after.channel == None):
            if(userdata["join_time"] == None): return 
            userdata = voice_data[guild_id][new_user]
            leave_time = time.time()
            passed_time = leave_time - userdata["join_time"]
            userdata["total_time"] += passed_time
            userdata["join_time"] = None
```

And here's the output:

```json
{
    "total_time": 7.4658853358879,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `datetime.timedelta` object, with some caveats.

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> data = {"total_time": 7.4658853358879}
>>> data["total_time"] = str(dt.timedelta(seconds=int(data["total_time"])))
>>> data
{'total_time': '0:00:07'}
```

If your time is greater than 1 day, or less than zero, the format starts including days

```
>>> str(dt.timedelta(days=1))
'1 day, 0:00:00'
>>> str(dt.timedelta(seconds=-1))
'-1 day, 23:59:59'
>>>
```